# Target specific child inside React loop with refs and state onClick

Tags: reactjs

I've got a mobile nav menu with a couple dropdown menus:

```
/* nav structure */
/about
    /portfolio
/services
    /service-1
    /service-2
contact
etc..
```

I'm creating this menu dynamically with a loop in my render function.

I've set up a *state variable* to assign a class to the *active* dropdown menu. I'm using an `onClick` event/attribute on the trigger element (a small arrow image) to apply an *active class* to the respective dropdown menu. Kinda...

```
const myNavMenu = () => {

    const [isSubMenuOpen, toggleSubMenu] = useState(false)

    return (
        <nav id="mainNav">
            <ul> 
                {navItems.items.map((item, i) => (
                  <li key={i} className={
                    (item.child_items) !== null ? 'nav-item has-child-items' : 'nav-item'}>
                    <Link to={item.slug}>{item.title}</Link>
                    {(item.child_items === null) ? null :
                      <>
                        <img className="arrow down" src={arrowDownImg} onClick={() => toggleSubMenu(!isSubMenuOpen)} />
                        {printSubMenus(item)}
                      </>
                    }
                 </li>
                ))}
             </ul>
           </nav>
         )
       }

    /**
       * Prints nav item children two levels deep 
       * @param {Obj} item a navigation item that has sub items
       */
  function printSubMenus(item) {
    return (
      <ul className={(isSubMenuOpen.current) ? "sub-menu sub-menu-open" : "sub-menu"}>
        {item.child_items.map( (childItem, i) => (
          <li className="nav-item" key={i}>
            <Link to={childItem.slug}>{childItem.title}</Link>
            {(childItem.child_items === null) ? null : 
            <>
              <ul className="sub-sub-menu">
                {childItem.child_items.map( (subItem, i) => (
                  <li className="sub-nav-item" key={i}>
                  <img className="arrow right" src={arrowRight} alt={''} />
                    <Link to={subItem.slug}>{subItem.title}</Link>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </>
            }  
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }

}
```

*`<Link>` is a [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) helper component that replaces `<a>` tags.

**The issue** is that when I click my trigger, the active class is being applied to both (all) sub-menus.

*I need to insert some sort of index (or Ref) on each trigger and connect it to their respective dropdowns but I'm not quite sure how to implement this.*

I was reading up on `useRef()` for use inside of function components. I believe that's the tool I need but I'm not sure how to implement it in a loop scenario. I haven't been able to find a good example online yet.

Thanks,

*p.s. my functions and loops are pretty convoluted. Very open to refactoring suggestions!*

Answer (score 0):

Move sub-menu to a new react component and put all the related logic in there (applying class included).

Comment: Okay, and pass a prop down to the new component? This is  basic react logic huh?